# How to reset all counters at once?

Tags: counters

I have several environments in my .tex file. I'd like to know if there is a way to reset all counters at once?

To clarify what I mean, suppose we have environments `theorem`, `proposition`, etc., and instead of using individual commands `\setcounter{theorem}{0}`, `\setcounter{proposition}{0}`, etc, for resetting the counters to 0 I'd like to know if there is a way for resetting all counters using a single command.

Thanks

Comment: By "all counters" you probably mean just a subset of counters. You don't want the `page` counter reset as well, right?

Comment: there's nothing to keep you from defining a command, say `\resetthmcounters`, to reset the subset of counters you want reset, but you'll still have to specify each counter individually within the expansion of that command.  i know of nothing automatic that knows *which* counters you care about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just reset *all* counters. Well, that's not entirely true; but it's probably not what you want (for example, the `page` counter should most likely not be reset...).

You could create a command that takes a list of counters for possible resetting. Here's such an implementation:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr,etoolbox}
\newcounter{resetdummycounter}
\newcommand{\resetcounterlist}[1]{%
  % Add each item to clear-list for resetdummycounter
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\counterwithin*{##1}{resetdummycounter}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}% Process list
\newcommand{\resetcounters}{\stepcounter{resetdummycounter}}
```

`\resetcounterlist{<CSV list>}` takes a `<CSV list>` of counters that you want to have reset. Then, issuing `\resetcounters` will reset the counters in `<CSV list>` to zero. Here's a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\usepackage{chngcntr,etoolbox}
\newcounter{resetdummycounter}
\newcommand{\resetcounterlist}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\counterwithin*{##1}{resetdummycounter}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}
\newcommand{\resetcounters}{\stepcounter{resetdummycounter}}

% These counters should be reset via \resetcounters
\resetcounterlist{theorem, proposition, corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} Some theorem \end{theorem}

\begin{proposition} Some proposition \end{proposition}

\begin{theorem} Some theorem \end{theorem}

\begin{proposition} Some proposition \end{proposition}

\begin{corollary} Some corollary \end{corollary}

\noindent\hrulefill

\resetcounters% Reset all counters previously marked

\begin{theorem} Some theorem \end{theorem}

\begin{proposition} Some proposition \end{proposition}

\begin{theorem} Some theorem \end{theorem}

\begin{proposition} Some proposition \end{proposition}

\begin{corollary} Some corollary \end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Note that this might confuse [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).